# How can I apply effects like a swirl to a webcam stream using Python and OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing, webcam

I am working on a school project where I want to simulate an LSD trip by applying various effects to a webcam stream in real time. I am using Python and OpenCV to capture and display the webcam stream. The effects I would like to apply are: ghost effect (similar to this https://www.learnpythonwithrune.org/opencv-python-webcam-create-a-ghost-effect/), more vibrancy/saturation in colors, slight blurriness, distorted outer edes and a kind of swirl effect (similar to this https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-checkered-pattern-with-spiral-twirl-swirl-distortion-effect-104721121.html)

I have already been able to capture and display the webcam stream using OpenCV's cv2.VideoCapture and cv2.imshow functions. However, I am having trouble figuring out how to apply effects like a swirl to the stream.

I have tried using OpenCV's cv2.getRotationMatrix2D and cv2.warpAffine functions to apply a swirl effect, but the output is not what I expected.

Is there any solutions to this? Or should I go about it another way.

This is what I've got at so far:

`

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Open the webcam
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Initialize the previous frame to None
frame_prev = None

while True:
    # Capture a frame from the webcam
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    # If this is the first frame, store it as the previous frame
    if frame_prev is None:
        frame_prev = frame.copy()
    
    # Apply the ghost effect by blending the current frame with a slightly transparent previous frame
    alpha = 0.5
    frame = cv2.addWeighted(frame, 1-alpha, frame_prev, alpha, 0)
    
    # Update the previous frame
    frame_prev = frame.copy()
    
    # Apply slight blur
    frame = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (5, 5), 0)
    
    # Increase saturation
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    frame[:,:,1] = np.clip(frame[:,:,1] * 1.5, 0, 255)
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
    
    # Distort outer edges
    height, width = frame.shape[:2]
    center = (width//2, height//2)
    radius = min(width, height) // 2
    mask = np.zeros((height, width), np.uint8)
    cv2.circle(mask, center, radius, (255, 255, 255), thickness=-1)
    mask = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel=np.ones((radius//10, radius//10), np.uint8))
    frame = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (3, 3), 0)
    frame = cv2.seamlessClone(frame, frame_prev, mask, center, cv2.NORMAL_CLONE)
    
    # Display the result
    cv2.imshow('Webcam', frame)
    
    # Check for user input
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:  # Esc key to exit
        break

# Release the webcam and close all windows
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

`

Thanks for any help, it is appreciated since I am very new to coding.

Comment: What does seamless cloning have to do with a swirl effect?  What research have you done. see twirl effect at http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html

Comment: See also http://supercomputingblog.com/openmp/image-twist-and-swirl-algorithm/.  Also https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/31datatype/Swirl.java.html Search Google!

Comment: Skimage has a swirl effect. See https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/transform/plot_swirl.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do the swirl animation using Python/OpenCV/Skimage.

- Read the input
- Set the arguments
- Loop over the input image and increase the swirl amount (strength) and use skimage swirl to apply the transform saving the results in PIL format
- Loop over the input image and decrease the swirl amount (strength) and use skimage swirl to apply the transform saving the results in PIL format
- When all the frames have been generated and saved in the frames list, use PIL to write the animation to a disk file

Input:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from skimage.transform import swirl
from PIL import Image


img = cv2.imread("mandril.jpg")

# get dimensions
h, w = img.shape[:2]

# get center
cx = w//2
cy = h//2

# set amount, number of frames and delay
max_amount = 20
dist = min(h,w)/2
angle = 0
num_frames = 50
delay = 50
border_color = (128,128,128)


frames = []
# loop and increase swirl
for i in range(0,num_frames):

    # compute phase to increment over 360 degree for number of frames specified so makes full cycle
    amount = i*max_amount/num_frames

    # do swirl
    result = swirl(img, center=(cx,cy), rotation=angle, strength=amount, radius=dist, preserve_range=True).astype(np.uint8)
        
    # show result
    cv2.imshow('result', result)
    cv2.waitKey(delay)

    # convert to PIL format and save frames
    result = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    pil_result = Image.fromarray(result)
    frames.append(pil_result)

# loop and decrease swirl
for i in range(0,num_frames):

    # compute phase to increment over 360 degree for number of frames specified so makes full cycle
    amount = (num_frames-i)*max_amount/num_frames

    # do swirl
    result = swirl(img, center=(cx,cy), rotation=angle, strength=amount, radius=dist, preserve_range=True).astype(np.uint8)
        
    # show result
    cv2.imshow('result', result)
    cv2.waitKey(delay)

    # convert to PIL format and save frames
    result = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    pil_result = Image.fromarray(result)
    frames.append(pil_result)

# write animated gif from frames using PIL
frames[0].save('mandril_swirl_animation.gif',save_all=True, append_images=frames[1:], optimize=False, duration=delay, loop=0)
```

[Full Size Animation](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/misc_tests/mandril_swirl_animation.gif)

Reduced Size Animation:

[image]